# VB.net and SQL Server 2005 Setting up Database password for standalone app

Tags: .net, sql, database, vb.net, sql-server-2005

Well, I am currently developing an application where different users can login using their email. The application will save the mail details (sender, message, receiver, attachment, etc)  to the database.

My problem is, **I don't want the user to have access to the database when using sql server management studio** (maybe some techie users would open their sql and edit the the message there, so yea.. I needed some security for the app.).

My solution is **i have to set a username/password to the DATABASE only**. Is this even possible? OR maybe you can suggest me some ways where the user can't access the sql management studio?

-**the application will be deployed on different computers with different servers at different places. Like a standalone app.**

hehe. Sorry if my question isn't making any sense, this is my first project on a company so I don't really have that much knowledge yet regarding these things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any login credentials that your app can use, the user can extract using a decompiler.

You should create a separate DB user for the app that doesn't have write access to things you don't want users to change.

Comment: thank you for your reply :D
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189522.aspx

I was reading this post, is this what you were suggesting? I don't know how to integrate it with the app yet but I'll get back here as soon as I get it right :)

Comment: thanks, hmm.. I guess that the link you gave me would require me to go the place where the app is supposed to be installed? I mean, I'm from philippines and then if the user is from canada do I have to configure it manually for them?

Comment: @Codemunkeee: No; you just create a login in your database (in SQL server), then change the app to use that login.

Comment: OK thanks! I'll try it out and mark this as solved as soon as I got this.

Comment: sir, I have already set a password for my database! Thanks! However, I can still attach the database and see the data when using sql server management studio. Is there any other way the user "would not be able to attach / prompt a username and password" before attaching the database?

Comment: @Codemunkeee: Disable Windows Authentication