# SQL Server Login Disable windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

my database filename is crystal.mdf, I tried adding logins with the help from this link [VB.net and SQL Server 2005 Setting up Database password for standalone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897518/vb-net-and-sql-server-2005-setting-up-database-password-for-standalone-app)

I can login using sql server authentication using a password and username.

The problem is, **I CAN open the database using windows authentication**.
This will allow the user (if the user is a techie guy and would like to dig things up) to change the values on the database, which might give errors to my application..

I don't want the users to open the database using windows authentication for security purposes, because I will deploy the application on a different place.

To summarize,

I want to disable windows authentication (is this even possible?)
If not, how can I, atleast make the database secure that the user won't be able to open it via windows authentication?

**EDIT**

[Answer from different forum](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53357/sql-server-2005-and-standalone-vb-application)

Comment: That's the wrong reason to disable windows authentication. Windows authentication is safer that sql server authentication. You can't fake the windows account, while the password will appear in the connection string. Besides, how will the DBA manage the database?

Comment: thanks for your insights @ panagiotis .. the main reason why I wanted to disable that authentication is because I will install the app on another pc along with an sql server installer as well, it is like a standalone application. I don't know how to do this yet because this is my first time deploying an application to other computers..

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10):

You can disable the Windows Authenticated User by : Security Tab --> logins --> Right click on that login -> Properties -> status ->Enable/Disable -> click Disable

OR

```
ALTER LOGIN [Domain\username] DISABLE
```

Comment: You can delete the particular WindowsUser login by right click and delete

Answer (score -1):

At the moment you may can't do this. Backup all DBs(not into default location) and re-install SQL Server using create fresh windows user account which have admin privileges. Then you can keep your windows authentication mode loin safer by protecting the windows user account.