# sql server configuration before open sql

Tags: sql-server, configuration

Sql server has two authentication mode but i need only sql server authentication mode when open sql server in dropdownlist how it is possible?

Comment: server properties -> security -> server auth. section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable it as mentioned here [SQL Server Login Disable windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974042/5725863)

> Security Tab --> logins --> Right click on that login -> Properties ->
>   status ->Enable/Disable -> click Disable

But SQL Server itself never allow you to Install it, unless you select it with Windows Authentication mode or Mixed Mode(Windows + SQL Server). Because Windows authentication is more secured as it is protected by   [kerberos protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29).